# HTTP/1.0 500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR in flask

Tags: python, mysql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have written a CRUD API in flask but whenever I try to make a GET request, I get this error saying "internal server error". POST requests are also not working for me. POST return a 400 error saying that it is a bad request. What am I doing wrong here?

Following is my run.py file

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, abort, request
from flask_restless import APIManager
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask import make_response

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_pyfile('config.py')
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), primary_key=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(50))
    name = db.Column(db.String(20))

    def __init__(self, name, uname, pword):
        self.username = uname
        self.name = name
        self.password = pword

@app.route('/api/users/', methods = ['GET'])
def index():
    return jsonify({'users': User.query.all()})

@app.route('/api/<string:username>/')
def get_user(username):
    return jsonify({'users': User.query.get(username)})

@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error):
    return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'Not found'}), 404)

@app.route('/api/users/', methods = ['POST'])
def create_user():
    if not request.json or not 'name' in request.json:
        abort(400)
    user = User(request.json.username, request.json.get('name', ''), request.json.get('password',''))
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify( { 'User': user } ), 201

@app.route('/api/users/<string:username>', methods = ['DELETE'])
def delete_user(username):
    db.session.delete(Users.query.get(username))
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify( { 'result': True } )

@app.route('/api/users/<string:username>', methods = ['PUT'])
def update_user(username):
    user = User.query.get(username)
    user.username = request.json.get('username', ser.username)
    user.name = request.json.get('name',user.name)
    user.focus = request.json.get('password', user.password)
    db.session.commit()
    return jsonify( { 'user': user } )

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Following is my config.py file

```
import os
basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = 'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.sqlite')
SQLALCHEMY_MIGRATE_REPO = os.path.join(basedir, 'db_repository')
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: If you run the app with `debug=True`, you will see a complete traceback, with an interactive web-based debugger, on the 500 error page.

Comment: @jwg I checked the console and it says "no such table: user [SQL: u'SELECT user.username AS user_username, user.password AS user_password, user.name AS user_name \nFROM user']"

Comment: Add a call to [`db.create_all()`](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/quickstart/#a-minimal-application) in a suitable place.

Comment: @TrailersAndMiscVideos do you have a table called 'user'?

Comment: yes, i do have that table

Answer (score 0):

You need to 'create' the User table after you define its class, otherwise it doesn't show up in memory. http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.1/api/#flask.ext.sqlalchemy.SQLAlchemy.create_all

The way to do it is:

```
class User(db.Model):
    username = db.Column(db.String(50), primary_key=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(50))
    name = db.Column(db.String(20))

    def __init__(self, name, uname, pword):
        self.username = uname
        self.name = name
        self.password = pword

db.create_all()

...the rest of your code
```